# Increment number until it matches another number

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write an algorithm that will increase `portion size` until the `total_cals` are as close to the specified argument `calories` as possible.

Here is my model:

```
class Foods(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   calories = models.IntegerField()
   protein = models.FloatField()
   carbs = models.FloatField()
   fat = models.FloatField()
   sugar = models.FloatField(null=True)
   fiber = models.FloatField(null=True)
   amount_in_grams = models.IntegerField(default=100)
   portion_size_in_grams = models.IntegerField()
```

Here is the function I have:

```
def mealPlanMaker(calories):
      total_cals = 0
      meal_dict = dict()
      meal = [Foods.objects.get(name='Rice'), Foods.objects.get(name='Broccoli'),
             Foods.objects.get(name='Chicken')]
      while calories > total_cals:
          for i in meal:
              portion_size = i.portion_size_in_grams + 1
              total_cals += i.calories * portion_size / 100
       meal_dict[i.name] = portion_size
       meals.append(meal_dict)
```

So what I want to do is increase the portion size until the `total_cals` is as close as possible to `calories`, say within a range of 50.

But my function doesn't work.

Comment: I have some ideas of why this won't work but before I answer, could you provide the error message please? You can add it to your question at the bottom, it just helps people diagnose the issue

Comment: ' meal_dict[i.name] = portion_size' here i  is outside of the for loop.


one more suggestion for calculating calories you don't need for loop. you can calculate directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that

1. `meal_dict` is defined somewhere so that `meal_dict[i.name] = portion_size` is not a syntax error.
2. The assignment to `meal_dict` is actually indented inside the for loop
3. You left out the return statement from your function

I'm not sure what your intention is. To start each meal at it's portion size and increase each by 1 gram until you hit the calorie limit?

You are not updating your portion size each time through the loop. Every time through the while loop you set it to the same values, one plus the portion size of each of the meals. Nothing in your code says make the portion size higher than it was the last time through the loop. But the portion_size is what you store in meal_dict.

```
def mealPlanMaker(calories):
    foods = Foods.objects.filter(name__in=['Rice', 'Broccolli', 'Chicken']) 

    meal_dict = {food.name: food.portion_size for food in foods}

    total_cals = sum(food.calories * food.portion_size / 100 for food in foods)

    while calories > total_cals:
        for food in foods:
            meal_dict[food.name] += 1
        total_cals = sum(food.calories * meal_dict[food.name] / 100 for food in foods)

    foods = list(foods)
    foods.append(meal_dict)
    
    return foods
```

You can also do this without the while loop.

```
def mealPlanMaker(calories):
    foods = Foods.objects.filter(name__in=['Rice', 'Broccolli', 'Chicken'])

    total_cals = sum(food.calories * food.portion_size / 100 for food in foods)

    calories_short = calories - total_cals

    calories_per_gram = sum(food.calories * 1 / 100 for food in foods)

    # // is integer division in python3
    extra_grams_needed = calories_short // calories_per_gram

    meal_dict = {food.name: food.portion_size + extra_grams_needed
                 for food in foods}

    foods = list(foods)
    foods.append(meal_dict)

    return foods
```

Comment: Thanks. What about if i wanted to increment the chicken portion by `x` and the rice portion by `y` and not increment the broccolli?

Comment: The function as you wrote it is hard coded to have those three foods. Perhaps you should write the function to take a list of food names as the second parameter. Then you can subtract the brocolli calories from the total before calling the function and pass the other two food names to the function. But I can't write your entire application logic in a comment. :-)